# Finitely generated module $N$ with two inequivalent decompositions to direct sums of indecomposable modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra, direct-sum

The Krull-Schmidt theorem says that the decomposition of a finite-length module as a direct sum of indecomposable modules is unique up to isomorphisms and permutations of the indecomposable modules.  Is there a counterexample to this if you replace "finite-length" with "finitely generated"?  That is, is there an example of a finitely generated module $N$ over a ring such that $N$ has two inequivalent decompositions to direct sums of indecomposable modules?

I know the example must be of infinite length. I believe it exists but still cannot find it.

Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R$ be any Dedekind domain that is not a PID and let $I\subset R$ be a non-principal ideal.  Then $I$ is a finitely generated projective $R$-module, so it is a direct summand of $R^n$ for some $n$.  Writing $R/I$ as a direct sum of indecomposable modules, we get a decomposition of $R^n\cong I\oplus R/I$ as a direct sum of indecomposable modules, where one of the indecomposable modules is $I$.  This decomposition is then inequivalent to the decomposition $R^n\cong R\oplus R\oplus\dots\oplus R$, since $I$ is not principal.

(More generally, a similar construction works for any Noetherian ring $R$ which is indecomposable as a module over itself and over which there is a finitely generated projective module that is not free.  (The Noetherian condition is needed to be sure that the decomposition can be refined to one consisting of indecomposable modules.))

Comment: Could you please clarify why $I$ is indecomposable?

Comment: Well, for instance, it is torsion-free, so any decomposition of $I$ would give a decomposition of $I\otimes_R K$ where $K$ is the fraction field of $R$.  But $I\otimes_RK$ is 1-dimensional over $K$.

Comment: In any case, indecomposability of $I$ is not actually needed for the argument--you can just split it into indecomposable modules, and not all of those modules can be isomorphic to $R$ since otherwise $I$ would be free.

Comment: thank you, I got it!

Comment: One more query: why cannot $I$ be free?

Comment: Again, by tensoring with $K$, if it were free, it would have to be free on one generator.  But it is not principal.

Comment: Okay, and why $I\otimes_R K$ is 1-dimensional over $K$? Sorry for stupid questions but I'm not that good at module theory...

Comment: $K$ is flat, so $I\otimes K$ is a submodule of $R\otimes K\cong K$.